# How to get rid of Nuget package's Entity Framework error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. It works fine, but every time I add a view (which successfully gets created) and then when I build solution I get error

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props.

I have to update (goes back to 6.1.3 version every time) Entity Framework which annoys me a lot. is there anything I can do to to solve this permanently?

**Edit:** here are all packages that uses `targetframework=net472`

```
<package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="FontAwesome" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="jQuery" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="jquery.datatables" version="1.10.15" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.19.4" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.9" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.9" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.9" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.12" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="PasswordHashTool" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="popper.js" version="1.16.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Comment: Try to remove the `packages` folder under solution directory, go to the _NuGet Package Manager_ and restore all packages. Don't forget exit from the Visual Studio and open the solution again. This might help.

Comment: @victor i tried that and added a view and build the solution and i got the error again

Comment: somehow entity framework changes from 6.4.4 version to 6.1.3 everytime this happens

Comment: @victor `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />`

Comment: All another packages in your project are using `targetFramework="net472"` too?

Comment: @victor should i post in comments or in edit post because every package uses that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247338/discussion-between-victor-and-salman-abbas).

Comment: Check if there's no reference to 6.1.3 in csproj files.

Comment: @GertArnold there wasn't. also i solved it by deleting EF from packages manually and then installing again as suggested by Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the following steps:

1. Exit from the Visual Studio.
2. Remove the `EntityFramework...` folder from the `packages`
3. Remove `<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net472" />` line from the `packages.config` file using a text editor.
4. Open the solution and add the required package `EntityFramework.6.4.4` again using the *NuGet Package Manager*.

> NOTE: Watch closely to the installation log. Probably you will see
> error related to the version conflict.